# Is there any danger if we use shared memory in Rcpp

Tags: r, shared-memory, rcpp

I am using shared memory (shmget system calls provided by C) to allocate shared memory from inside a RCpp program.
Here as i am not using standard Calloc function which is connected with memory management of R , is there any danger i should be aware of ?
Will the memory management of R sees the space allocated by shmget as free space and tries to over write anything to it ?
If that is the case , what can be done to avert this situation ?

Thanks
       Vineeth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows a complete lack of understanding of R.

You can neither make R multithreaded just by linking to pthreads, or using OpenMP, or ...  By the same token, "Writing R Extensions" is *very* clear about what can and cannot be done with memory allocation.  I suggest you take a closer look at that manual.

Comment: My sincere apologies on "jumping" into things and asking it right away. But then what i need is quite simple , i am providing R with 10 GB of data loaded into memory. This is provided through R studio server. Now whichever user logs in using the browser , he should be able to access this data. It would be a bad idea to load the info to all rsession process and simply multiplying the information. I tired shared memory and it seems to work fine so far. My sincere aplologies but i cant find anything related to R and shared memory in the net.

Comment: I believe shared memory is allocated in a pol outside heap and hence R should not be aware of it. From "writing R extensions" on "Transient storage allocation"- "This memory is taken from the heap". So to my best knowledge there should not be any issues in allocating shared memory in R , and other R instances accessing it. Kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If you look into external pointers, and the XPtr class in Rcpp, then you can manage a pool of memory outside of R. See for example the bigmemory package which does that (not using Rcpp).  And that is NOT the same as shared memory in the parallel computing sense, and you risk not getting taken very sriously by randomly throwing terms around.

Comment: thanks @dirk Eddelbuettel . I will carefully look into it. On another note i feel this might not cause any issues. Shared memory would be allocated by a different process than R. This shared memory would be accessed by R. Hence the memory is not actually in R's heap and it can access it. Does this idea look good ?

Comment: -1 It is really necessary to be so aggressive and snarky ?

Comment: @statquant It's Dirk.  So yes :D

Comment: @statquant Dirk is the new Brian Ripley, although being Eddelbuettel'ed doesn't sounds as good as being Ripley'ed.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: I will need to think about this. I think you are being more mean than complimentary. :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I got Ripley'ed once, waiting to be Eddelbuettel'ed ;).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: Oh I have been his target more than once, rest assured of that :)